# Search all versions of a file in git log takes long

Tags: java, jgit

I noticed that finding all versions of a specific file in git takes a long time when the number of files in the repo is more then a couple of thousand. Any idea how to improve the performance? Here is the code we use:

```
try (Git git = Git.init().setDirectory(targetDirectory).call()) {


            /* Find all versions in git logs */
            Iterable<RevCommit> logs3 = git.log().addPath(fileName + ".yaml").call();

            /* verCount has number of git versions for the page */
            int verCount = 0;
            for (RevCommit rev3 : logs3) {

                verCount++;             
                String versionName = "V." + verCount;
                final String versionID = rev3.getName();        
                final Date versionDate = rev3.getAuthorIdent().getWhen();
                final String versionComment = rev3.getFullMessage();
                final String versionAuthor = rev3.getAuthorIdent().getName();
                versionList.add(new VersionInfo(versionName, versionDate, versionAuthor,
                        versionID, versionComment));

            }


        }
```

Also is there a good way in Java to measure which line is taking long in my snippet? I have my guess but need to measure it somehow.

Comment: Did you run the same command with C-Git, to see if there is any room for improvement at all?

Comment: Hi @RüdigerHerrmann thanks for the suggestion. Do you mean https://git.zx2c4.com/cgit/? We used the ordinary git version 2.15.0

Comment: I mean native Git, the command line tool, i.e. `git log --path ...` or whatever is equivalent to the JGit code. If this isn't much faster than your code, then there is probably not much room for improvement

Comment: Thanks @RüdigerHerrmann the command line tool also takes a very long time.